# Java program name display

Tags: java

I have written some Java programs and exported them to jar files, which I have then run when I want. The problem is that on the bottom of the screen where I can click between them, they do not display any identifying information on their tabs, they just have the Java logo (for example, one can clearly identify different Chrome tabs through the page name displayed, their text editor from file name, etc).

Instead each of the Java programs are empty, and I would like to give them a name. But I can't figure out the correct terms to find an answer to this question through Google. I hope my question is clear. Is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: Are these terminal or GUI programs?

Comment: Can't you just set the title of the window?

Comment: Which GUI Framework are you using? SWING? SWT? Something completely different?

Comment: @coding monk forgive me, but I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the title either in the constructor or in the jframe.setTitle method.

See http://alvinalexander.com/java/jframe-title-set for a clear example.

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote for correct answer so you support the community :)